# Los iconos no funcionan en dispositivos moviles

Tags: html, css, material-design, font-awesome, icons

Tengo una página web que utiliza iconos de font-awesome, en el navegador de una pc funciona bien, pero al momento de ver el resultado en un dispositivo móvil los iconos no se muestran, en el caso de font-awesome solo deja el espacio y utilizando iconos de material-design me muestra el texto que hay en la etiqueta i.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Ejemplo</title>
        <link href="http://www.pilgrims.com.mx/pilgrimsweb/rec/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
        <i class="material-icons">face</i>
        <i class="material-icons">home</i>
        <i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>
        <i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>
        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
        <i class="material-icons">visibility</i>
    </body>
</html>
```

Como debería de verse / Como se ve en un dispositivo móvil real
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo por si acaso.... El dispositivo real tiene acceso a internet?  ya que estás descargando eso de internet: https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons no de archivos locales.

Comment: si, la página está en un servidor con acceso a internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que el dispositivo móvil no tiene acceso a internet, tendrás que descargar manualmente los archivos fuentes de `https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons` y `https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css`, los pones en una carpeta llamada **CSS** por ejemplo. Luego eliminas los links a estas rutas *(que requieren internet para traerlas)*, y añades los links a los archivos que descargaste. Ejemplo:

`<link href="http:tudominio.com/css/iconos-google.css" rel="stylesheet">`

*Nota: Las fuentes de google hacen una petición dentro del CSS a esta dirección `fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v47/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2`, deberías descargar este archivo también y reemplazar la ruta en el css que descargues de Google.*

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que ese móvil en concreto usa un navegador antiguo. Para solucionarlo, bastaría con añadir  el código de carácter tal que así:

```
<i class="material-icons face">&#xe87c;</i>
```

De todas formas, [puedes usar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitmagine.materialicon)